# <div>の中の文字列を上下で中央に揃える

Tags: html, css, html5

htmlでdivの中の文字列を上下で中央にそろえるにはどうすればいいのでしょうか?
divの中に文字列があり、`text-align: center`で左右は中央になったのですが上下で中央に揃えられません。

```css
div#div1 {
  text-align: center;
  height: 400px;
  width: 600px;
  border: solid 1px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test html</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="div1">Hello</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

styleに`display: table-cell;`を追加します。
(※css3)

Answer (score 2):

最近のブラウザだと、 flexbox を使う、という選択肢もありそうです。

参考: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22218694/3090068

```css
div#div1 {
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
  border: solid 1px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

わたしも初心者なので最適解はわかりませんが、
同じ悩みを以下の方法で解決しました。
ご参考まで。

文字列をpタグでくくり、

```
div#div1 p {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

でいかがでしょうか。